# What ties the various Final Fantasy series together, aside from the name?

Tags: video-games, final-fantasy

I've played several of the final fantasies over the years, and while they seem to have a few common elements, there seems to be some significant differences between the various worlds. Is there any commonality to the back stories of the final fantasies, or do they all take place in essentially different universes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Entries in the *Final Fantasy* series share a lot of themes and elements (Cid, chocobos, crystals), but most occur in different universes. Aside from the obvious sequels (e.g. *X* and *X-2*):

- Most games let you explore the entire world; there's nothing in the way of shared geography.
- The different games have vastly different technology levels, and presence of and systems of magic.
- The different games have different sentient and non-sentient species with different pre-game histories, often explored all the way back to the origin of the planet.

There are two exceptions. First, [Ivalice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivalice), the setting of *XII*, the Tactics games, and *Vagrant Story*. Second, the [Crystal Chronicles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Crystal_Chronicles_%28series%29) series contains several games in different genres, and all occur in the same universe.

Comment: Just to add to this: Final Fantasy 7 and Final Fantasy X (and therefore X-2) are set in the same universe. Shinra was founded by a descendent of a character from Final Fantasy X-2

Comment: @danrhul Why do you state that Final Fantasy X-2 is set in the same universe as FF7? Are there any references or sources you can give?

Comment: @Rufo Yes, see my answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76061/is-there-a-relationship-between-the-final-fantasy-games/76111#76111

Comment: Biggs and Wedge can be found in all the Main Franchise. The Creator was a big star Wars fan

Comment: Wait, does that actually imply different _universes_, or just different worlds?

Answer (score 3):

[Cid](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cid) is the only character that is consistant through all of the games.
All the games also share [gil](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gil).

Comment: Why the downvote?  Do you really think it isn't useful that I pointed out the evidence for the games being in the same universe and having the same monetary system?

Comment: I think "same monetary system" is a poor standard; how many universes use "dollars" or "credits"? A character (or more than one!) _named_ Cid is in all games, but he's hardly consistently portrayed.

Comment: I don't think they all take place in the same world. What led you to that?

Comment: Yeah, that was an unfounded assumption that I had always made based on the Gil system. I changed my answer.

Comment: Does your answer include the older games, like Final Fantasy Legend II on the GameBoy and Adventure and all that?  I'm not downvoting or trying to be rude - just genuinely curious if you went that far.  I would upvote this, if so.

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying that while each game has a character named Cid, they're not all the same character, as this answer implies. They have *similarities* - most, if not all, of the Cids are mechanics of some sort - but they're separate individuals.

Answer (score -3):

The themes and most of the other elements are the same in every series of  *Final Fantasy*.

1. Most of the games are conceptualized to explore the world, they share no geographical spaces.
2. The constant display of magic of the swords used in the series.
3. Every game has sections like pre-game histories, and this is one thing which *Final Fantasy* possesses.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This looks like a paraphrasing of [the accepted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16027/76048); you may wish to edit it so it looks less similar.